# How to encapsulate User Setting (Options Page) in Visual Studio 2010 AddIn

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I'm currently developping a Visual Studio Extension and I have a question about [Options Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166195.aspx). Options Page allows user to save setting about your Extension. Visual Studio handle a lot of work for us.

I created the Options Page.

```cs
public class VisualStudioParameter : DialogPage
{
    private string _tfsServerUrl = DefaultParameter.TfsServerUrl;

    [Category("TFS Parameters")]
    [DisplayName(@"Server Name")]
    [Description("The URL of your TFS Server")]
    public string TfsServerUrl
    {
        get { return _tfsServerUrl; }
        set { _tfsServerUrl = value; }
    }
}
```

First, I created a method in the Visual Studio Package to acces to the Options Page.
Okay so now, from my Package, I can easily acces to the settings.

```cs
partial class SpecFlowTfsLinkerExtensionPackage : Package : IParameter
{
    ....
    ....

    public string GetTfsServerUrl()
    {
        return ((VisualStudioParameter) GetDialogPage(typeof (VisualStudioParameter))).TfsServerUrl;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to be able, in another library (Another project, included in the VSIX Package), to get easily these values. I don't want to reference the Visual Studio AddIn Package in my library.

I also have Unit Test so I'm going to create an Interface. During Unit Test, I going to Mock the object.

```cs
public interface IParameter
{
    string GetTfsServerUrl();
}
```

Do you have any idea about how I can develop a clean solution to get these parameters from another assembly ?

Do you think the better solution is to inject the AddIn dependency in my library ?

If you already developed a Visual Studio Extension, How did you encapsulated the user setting from your core assembly ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: any solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that:

```cs
// Access DTE infrastructure
EnvDTE.DTE dte = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
// Access options page
var props = dte.get_Properties(@"Your Extension", "General");        
var pathProperty = props.Item("TfsServerUrl");
path = pathProperty.Value as string;
```

Comment: For more information see the bottom of this MSDN page in the `Accessing Options from the Hosting VSPackage` and `Accessing Options by using Automation` sections. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166195.aspx